# How to import a Common JS(?) module which exports as a callable, from TypeScript

Tags: typescript, commonjs

I have mixed JS/TS project

There is a JS library in the project that does this:

```js
module.exports = () => {
  // some logic conditional on env vars here
  // then...
  return {
    someMethod: () => { /* whatever */ },
    someOtherMethod: () => { /* whatever */ }
  }
}
```

Other `.js` files in the same project are able to import and use it like:

```js
import mymodule from '@project/mymodule';

mymodule.someMethod();
```

If I try to do the same from a `.tsx` file I get:

```
Module '"project/mymodule"' has no default export.
```

I have been trying to find the right incantation to import and use this module from TS but without success.

Elsewhere in the project someone had tried:

```js
import * as mymodule from '@project/mymodule';

/* @ts-expect-error: mymodule is commonjs export and could be swapped by webpack */
const { someMethod } = mymodule();
someMethod();
```

...but that doesn't actually work - the comment suppresses compile errors but the code was untested and raises this error if it is actually reached:

```
TypeError: mymodule is not a function
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

The project has a `tsconfig.json` file with:

```json
{
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution in the end...

We need to add a TS declaration file `mymodule.d.ts`

The declaration file should look like:

```js
declare function mymodule(): {
  someMethod: <appropriate signature here>;
  someOtherMethod: <appropriate signature here>;
};
export = mymodule;
```

That allows us to use same import form we were using from .js files:

```js
import mymodule from '@project/mymodule';
```

But TypeScript doesn't call the module function and return its result, as apparently happens when using it from JS, so we need to use the module differently in our TS files:

```js
import mymodule from '@project/mymodule';

const { someMethod, someOtherMethod } = mymodule();

someMethod();
```

(recall that in the .js files we can just do `mymodule.someMethod()`)